# Can I use Content Query Web Parts in Foundation?

Tags: content-query-web-part

I'm looking at using a CQWP in my project, but I need to make sure it's compatible with all the SharePoint versions we'll be implementing to.

I've seen some articles seeming to say it's MOSS only:

> The Content Query Web Part is available only in sites that are located
>   on a server running Office SharePoint Server 2007.

But I've also seen references to WSS versions:

> Some Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Content Query Web Part
>   properties are inherited from Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 ...

So, long story short: Please could you fill in any of the below boxes you're certain about?:

```
          | 2007| 2010|
----------|-----|-----|
Standard  |  Y  |  ?  |
----------|-----|-----|
Foundation|  ?  |  ?  |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Content Query web part is included in the SharePoint Standard SKU, which implies MOSS for the 2007 version of the product.

```
          | 2007| 2010|
----------|-----|-----|
Standard  |  Y  |  Y  |
----------|-----|-----|
Foundation|  N  |  N  |
```

I've tried to make a complete [reference table](http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/webparts.aspx) of all the SharePoint 2010 out-of-the-box web parts.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I'll use that handy reference next time too.